# Render different component based on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a component based on the condition.

```
exceptPath: ['home', 'person']
pathName = 'test'

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {this.state.exceptPathNames.map((exceptPathName) => {
      console.log(exceptPathName);
      pathName === exceptPathName ? console.log('test') : <LinkGridLayout />;
    })}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

If `pathName` is not `"home"` or `"person"` I want to return `<LinkGridLayout />` else do not return anything.

Comment: Is there any specific issue with what you are trying to do so far? What do you need help with? Would it be helpful for us to understand if you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how can I return LinkGridLayout if the pathName is not home or person

Comment: It's not pretty, but isn't that what the existing code you've shared is already doing? `pathName` isn't equal to any of the values in `exceptPath` and so `<LinkGridLayout />` is the result of evaluating the ternary expression. I guess all that is missing is returning some valid JSX.

Comment: you just need to `return` it.

Comment: I tried returning but it renders twice:                     ```return pathName === exceptPathName ? null : <LinkGridLayout />;``` I guess because it iterates through the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is render a `LinkGridLayout` component for any `pathName` value that ***is not*** `"home"` or `"person"` (*or any value in `excludePath` really*) then I'd suggest the following refactor to check that no elements in the array equal the `pathName`, and if so, conditionally render `LinkGridLayout`.

Example:

```
exceptPath: ['home', 'person']
```

```
return (
  <>
    {!exceptPath.some((exceptPathName) => pathName === exceptPathName) && (
      <LinkGridLayout />
    )}
  </>
);
```

or

```
return (
  <>
    {exceptPath.every((exceptPathName) => pathName !== exceptPathName) && (
      <LinkGridLayout />
    )}
  </>
);
```